# How to bypass router access control?

Tags: windows-8, router, ip, mac-address

For the past month, me and my father have been having a friendly war about the internet in my household. Basically, after 9:30 at night, he turns off my internet, by setting a schedule that stops a group of IP objects from accessing the internet (this includes my laptop, phone, iPod, etc.) Before this, he accidentally left the router password on my laptop, saved, so I was able to go in, and just change the IP objects to a different one, allowing my computer to connect.

Now that he has changed the password, I was wondering if there was a way to:

1. change my MAC address, so it won't bind to the same IP
2. have a different way of bypassing it.

This is all for fun and games, we both enjoy trying to figure out what the other has done.

The operating environment:
OS: Windows 8
Router: Draytek Vigor 2820

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed change your MAC address on your Network Interface Card (NIC) in Windows options.

`Start > Device Manager > Pick your network card from the list > Advanced tab`

You should see this (please excuse my foreign Windows language):

[image]

From here you can change your MAC address. Windows accepts a MAC address with no dashes or spaces, so for example `01-23-45-67-89-ab` should be entered as `0123456789ab`.

The only way I can think of to bypass the router would be to factory reset it, then change the password away from the default password so your father cant access it and then start blocking *his* devices instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your router works, but if it really blocks certain IP addresses (instead of MAC addresses) - you could try to change the IP on your Computer directly - no need for router access to do this.

In your network settings, try to set the IP to manual configuration.

Network and Sharing Center > Local Area Connection > Local Area Connection Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4):

- Deselect "Option an IP address automatically
- Select "Use the following IP address" and enter similar values to what works before 9:30pm (e.g. change from 192.168.0.14 to 192.168.0.140)
- Use the same subnet mask and gateway as during the day

If you are unlucky the router might also only allow certain devices (like Kristian) suggested, you would then have to adjust your MAC address to imitate one of them. However, this will most likely lead to issues in your network, since two computers can't have the same IP in a network.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old,but I've tested that plugging another router and connecting to that, I was able to go past the time

A weird bug I experience is if you are connected to a server of some sort you are able to continue using the services, like I was able to keep playing games on steam and was able to download things on their services as long as I was connected to them before the time cut occurred. My guess is that you can use a VPN to stay on the internet past the time, as long as you connect before the time cut happens.

Comment: VPN does not obscure your connection IP on the router you are connected to. Different routers have different methods for cutting off access. In your case it sounds as though the router only blocks new connections, or only blocks port 80 (http/web) traffic.